# How can I add a login area with a custom skin in DotNetNuke?

Tags: authentication, dotnetnuke, customization, skinning

I am developing a skin where I would like to bring in the login area (similar to account login module) so that a login area would appear in all the pages where this skin is applied.

How can I achieve this? Are there any skin objects for this? Please suggest any alternatives possible through DotNetNuke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the Login Skin object.

[Here](http://www.10poundgorilla.com/DotNetNuke/Tools-Resources/Skinning-Tool.aspx) is some documentation on the available skin objects.

And some more [Links](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/page/skin-objects) to related topics.